# How to add the Tawk chat widget script to nextjs react app

Tags: javascript, next.js, tawk.to

I'm trying to figure out how to add a chat widget from Tawk to a next.js react app.

In my _app.js, I have added the script import tag and tried to set the widget as follows:

```
import Script from 'next/script'

      {/* <!--Start of Tawk.to Script--> */}
      <Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload">
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: `
            
            var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
            (function(){
            var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/[]/[]';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
            })();
           
            `,
        }}
      </Script>
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

> Unhandled Runtime Error SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>
> Call Stack loadScript ../../node_modules/next/dist/client/script.js
> (148:18) eval ../../node_modules/next/dist/client/script.js (167:62)

I contacted the tawk dev support team, who acknowledged an issue with react, and suggested that a fix had been pushed with a new version 2.0.1 heres the link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react

When I try that both in _app.tsx and _document.tsx, I get more than 10 errors with that package.

Has anyone figured out how to use tawk in a next.js react app?

Comment: for others that might be facing the same issue, I spoke to the tawk dev support. They have identified an issue with react and are working on a solution. I will update this post to share the solution when one is available.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made a working project with a real Tawk.to account:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tawk-test-ovmsqy?file=/pages/_app.js

You should change the ids at `s1.src` line!

```
import Script from "next/script";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      <Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload">
        {`
            var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
            (function(){
            var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/62f4b8c537898912e962654a/1ga5v3hhr';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
            })();  
        `}
      </Script>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is outside the tag you have it like this:

```
<Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload">
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
```

should be:

```
<Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={"your data"} />
```

However, it is best to include the code inside the tag. Your `_app.js` should look like this:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import Script from "next/script";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
      {/* <!--Start of Tawk.to Script--> */}
      <Script id="tawk" strategy="lazyOnload">
        {`
            var Tawk_API=Tawk_API||{}, Tawk_LoadStart=new Date();
            (function(){
            var s1=document.createElement("script"),s0=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
            s1.async=true;
            s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/[]/[]';
            s1.charset='UTF-8';
            s1.setAttribute('crossorigin','*');
            s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1,s0);
            })();
        `}
      </Script>
    </>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't produce an error, but it also doesnt display the widget.

Comment: Sure I guess you didn't replace this : ` s1.src='https://embed.tawk.to/[]/[]'; `  by the url of your account. Where the `[ ]` go, goes the info that associates the widget to your tawk account.

Comment: I did- I just removed those strings for this post

Comment: the url should be like: https://embed.tawk.to/12345678/default

Comment: the tawk app does not use the word default - it uses random strings for both ids. Are you saying I'm supposed to substitute the second string for the word "default"?

Comment: I tried replacing the second string with default and a tawk error is returned in the console that says 'connection refused'

Comment: I also tried adding the two random string id I get from tawk, in the script, in _document.tsx - and I still dont get the widget to load.

Comment: try this url https://embed.tawk.to/56d59cac343e11f1034e44dc/default. I extracted it from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725713/live-chat-jquery-plugin-tawk-to-not-visible I tested it in next and with this url you will see that the widget appears. That means your url is wrong.

Comment: When I copy the url direct from the tawk widget script or the id fields in the tawk chat dash page, I do not get the console error - but the widget does not display. Both of those sources use two separate strings for id fields. When I try replacing the second id field with the word 'default', I get a connection refused error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to create a twik.js file in the public folder and load it with next/script without any issues

Comment: I am asking this question because of the issues I'm having.

Comment: @Mel ye just create a twik.js file with the contents to init the twik chat widget after that you can use next/script with the property src pointing to /twik.js on Script

Answer (score 1):

For cleaner approach you can use `@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react` at [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tawk.to/tawk-messenger-react)